# Trying to install boost 1_70 C++ in MS visual studio code but getting "No such files exists"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, boost, mingw

I am following [this](https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6) procedure. And I am using MS visual studio code with minGW compiler with code runner extension. I've built b2 engine successfully I suppose. Here is the output

```js
boost-install.generate-cmake-config-version- C:\Program Files\boost\lib\cmake\boost_math_tr1l-1.70.0\boost_math_tr1l-config-version.cmake boost-install.generate-cmake-variant- C:\Program Files\boost\lib\cmake\boost_math_tr1l-1.70.0\libboost_math_tr1l-variant-mgw92-mt-d-x32-1_70-static.cmake boost-install.generate-cmake-config- 
C:\Program Files\boost\lib\cmake\boost_math-1.70.0\boost_math-config.cmake boost-install.generate-cmake-config-version- 
C:\Program Files\boost\lib\cmake\boost_math-1.70.0\boost_math-config-version.cmake ...
failed updating 678 targets... ...skipped 278 targets... ...updated 16845 targets...
```

Task.json

```html
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "-L",
                "-1",
                "-IC:\\Program Files\\boost\\include\\boost-1_70",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And c_cpp_properties.json

```html
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\include\\boost-1_70"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Following is the code I am trying to run:

```html
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " ");
}
```

But getting the following error:

```html
    PS C:\Users\dwiti\OneDrive\Documents\My Bluetooth> cd "c:\Users\dwiti\OneDrive\Documents\My Bluetooth\" ; if ($?) { g++ worthless.cpp -o worthless } ; if ($?) { .\worthless }        
worthless.cpp:2:10: fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Note- I am using MinGW g++ compiler and have successfully added the respected environment paths as well. And I have already tried all the previous answers solution but they are not working out for me due to some reason which I don't understand. Please do help me out in resolving this issue.
Thanks!.

Comment: I think I am unable to configure the Include path properly in task.json file & cpp_properties.json file. Else everything else seems good to me.

Comment: Any reason you're not not building a more recent version of boost (latest is 1.75.0)?
Which version is MinGW GCC (`gcc --version`)?

Comment: I am using MinGw 9.2.0. 
Also due to some reason I was facing an error while building the b2.exe from 1.75 version of boost.
And this issue is common to many windows based users. Which is why I backtracked to 1.70

Comment: @Evgeny please look into this. I am stuck at this for quite a while.